# s3zipper has limited to download only 1000 files from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am using [s3zipper](https://github.com/Teamwork/s3zipper) along with PHP to stream zip S3 files. However there is one issue. We have more than 1000 of files to download (approx 2K to 10K varying). So when we send request to s3zipper lets say 1500 files, we were getting only 1000 files within a zip.

As per [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) docs they have 1000 keys limitation i.e.

> S3 API version 2 implementation of the GET operation returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket.

. So if we want to get more than than we have to use **marker parameter** AWS A. But in [s3zipper.go](https://github.com/Teamwork/s3zipper/blob/master/s3zipper.go) this call `aws_bucket.GetReader(file.S3Path)`, is reading file and adding to zip.I am not sure how I can use marker in this case.

I am curious how we can come over from this limitation. I am newbie to Go language, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Saw you got a response at http://engineroom.teamwork.com/how-to-securely-provide-a-zip-download-of-a-s3-file-bundle/. Is this question still valid?

Comment: @jbird, yes still valid because we are having entries in our local database, I checked it thoroughly, we are sending more than 1000 files to s3zipper. Even to check at s3zipper end, I forked s3zipper. I chunk out 1000 files per iteration each loop. I thought reinitialising aws_bucket will do the trick but with no success. Here is my forked [s3zipper](https://github.com/sukhjindersingh/s3zipper/blob/master/s3zipper.go)

Comment: did you end up fixing this problem?